# Multiple buildSrc folders with Kotlin Gradle and Git submodule

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have an Android project with Kotlin Gradle (main project). This project also contains the Git submodule, which also uses Kotlin Gradle (submodule project).

The main project has a `buildSrc` folder with `Configuration` class inside. The submodule project also has its own `buildSrc` folder with `Configuration` class inside.

The main project uses `module1` and `module2` from the submodule project. These modules use the `Configuration` class from the submodule project in the `build.gradle.kts` files.

**Here comes the problem**: when I connect `module1` and `module2` to my main project, the compile error is raised because the `buildSrc` folder from the submodule project is not compiled, but `buildSrc` from the main module will be compiled.

**The question is next**: how can I merge `buildSrc` folders and if I can't, so how I should handle this situation?

**Note**: I don't want just copy-paste classes from the submodule's `buildSrc` folder to the main's `buildSrc`. I want to reuse this submodule in other projects.

Here is simplified project structure:

```
+-- app/
+-- android-sub/ (submodule)
|   +-- app/
|   +-- module1/
|       +-- build.gradle.kts
|   +-- module2/
|       +-- build.gradle.kts
|   +-- build/
|   +-- buildSrc/
|       +-- build/
|       +-- build.gradle.kts
|       +-- src/main/java
|           +-- Configuration
|    +-- gradle/
|    +-- build.gradle.kts
|    +-- gradlew
|    +-- gradlew.bat
|    +-- gradle.properties
|    +-- settings.gradle.kts
+-- build/
+-- buildSrc/
|   +-- build/
|   +-- build.gradle.kts
|   +-- src/main/java/
|       +-- Configuration
+-- gradle/
+-- build.gradle.kts
+-- gradle.properties
+-- gradlew
+-- gradlew.bat
+-- local.properties
+-- settings.gradle.kts
```

The main project's `settings.gradle.kts`:

```
include ':app', ':module1', ':module2'
project(':module1').projectDir = new File(rootDir, 'android-sub/module1')
project(':module2').projectDir = new File(rootDir, 'android-sub/module2')
```

Comment: What role does `Configuration` play in your build? Also could you share the `settings.gradle.kts` from the root project?

Comment: @LouisJacomet the `Configuration` class is just an example and contains some values and methods (maybe).

Comment: @LouisJacomet added `settings.gradle.kts`

Answer (score 3):

In a given Gradle build, there can be only one `buildSrc`.

Here however your are attempting to compose two independent Gradle builds by stitching them together in one.

I would recommend instead to look at [Gradle composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/composite_builds.html), which will allow you to compose two full builds, each with their own `buildSrc`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This is a very nice solution. But, using composing builds we still have a problem: we cannot re-use code in different buildSrc modules. As I understand, now we have only two options with its own limitations: 1. Composing builds. 2. Soft links.